# Return multiple results

Tags: python, get

Below code only returns 1 result even though there are more than 1 record with matching ID

```
@app.route('/api/PDL/<int:task_id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_task(task_id):
    task = [task for task in tasks if task['id'] == task_id]
    if len(task) == 0:
        abort(404)
    return jsonify({'task': task[0]})
```

What should I do to return all results ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to remove `[0]` in

```
return jsonify({'task': task})
```